# Radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the radius of convergence for: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n}}{n!}z^{n} $$

My attempt:

Let $$c_{n}=\frac{n^{n}}{n!}$$

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |c_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}$$

$$=\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^{1/n}{(n-1)^{1/n}(n-2)^{1/n}\cdots 2^{1/n}1^{1/n}}}$$

The denominator $$n^{1/n}{(n-1)^{1/n}(n-2)^{1/n}\cdots 2^{1/n}1^{1/n}}$$ goes to 1 and so the limit goes to $\infty$

So the radius of convergence is $1/\infty=0$
Is that right?

Comment: No. Consider Stirling's formula for $n!$.

Comment: Note my edits to the question, using $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}$ rather than $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} Sup. \qquad$

Comment: @saulspatz Stirling's formula is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, of course it's unnecessary to solve the problem, by it explains the flaw in OP's reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

Using ratio test would be easy here. Consider
$$\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} = \frac{n^n}{n!}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac 1 {(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right| = \frac 1 e$$
So the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: For the ratio test, you need the limit to exist if you want to determine the radius of convergence (consider $c_n = 3 + (-1)^n$). From $\limsup$ or $\liminf$, you can only get bounds for the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

By [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), the [Lambert function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) $W$ has the following Taylor series at the origin:
$$ W(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\,x^n $$
whose radius of convergence equals $\frac{1}{e}$. It leads to 
$$ \frac{W(x)}{1+W(x)} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^{n}}{n!}\,x^n$$
then to:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!}\,x^n = \frac{-W(-x)}{1+W(-x)} $$
for any $|x|<\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Complete and utter overkill ... so (+1) ... ;-)) ... and I thought my answer  might be too much.

Comment: Nothing wrong with striking a small pea with a sledgehammer!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. Applying the ratio test,
$$
\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!n^n}|z|=\frac{(n+1)(n+1)^n}{(n+1)n^n}|z|=\left (\frac{n+1}{n}\right )^n|z|=\left (1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^n|z|.
$$
Since the first term tends to $e$ for $n \to \infty$, the ratio is strictly smaller than one iff $|z|<e^{-1}$.

Your mistake comes from the fact that it is true that individual terms at the denominator go to zero, but the number of individual terms grows with $n$, so you cannot apply that reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

This is more easily done with the ratio test.

$\frac {(n+1)^{n+1}} {(n+1)!} \frac {n!} {n^n} = (\frac {n+1} {n})^n$

which goes to $e$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so the radius of convergence is $\frac {1} {e}.$

Answer (score 0):

> **If one wishes to use the root test, then one can proceed as follows.**

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac n{(n!)^{1/n}}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac kn\right)\right)^{-1/n}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1-\frac kn\right)}\\\\
&=e^{-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1-\frac kn\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\int_0^1 \log(1-x)\,dx}\\\\
&=e^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Hence, the series converges for $|z|<1/e$.

Comment: Happy New Year!  And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.